# how to use expo-sqlite execute sql with typescript?

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

Hi all I want to use expo-sqlite to transaction object to execute an sql statement.

However, I got a problem in define the return value of the error function.

Here is the example code:

```
tx.executeSql(

    // sql statement (ok)
    "...",

    // input arguments (ok)
    [...],

    // success case: since I use it in a promise, so I use: resolve(...) (ok)
    () => {
          resolve()
        },

    // failed case: I want to reject it, use reject()
    // But I got an Error here! (Wrong!!!)
    // Here ask me to return a boolean value, but how??? true or false???
    (_, err) => {
          reject(err) // not enough???
       }
      )
```

From the type definition file, I know, I need to return a boolean value for the **error callback function**, but which one? true or false???

Do you have some idea how to do it???

PS. Here is official doc about the expo-sqlite: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why the error callback function does need a return type of boolean. Since we resolve/reject the promise anyways I think we can savely ignore the return type.

Below you can find my typescript synchronous example:

```js
export const fetchTypeSaveSql = async <T>(sqlStatement: string, args: any[] | undefined): Promise<T[]> => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                sqlStatement, args,
                (_, result) => {
                    resolve(Array.from(result.rows as any) as T[])
                },
                (_, error): boolean => {
                    console.warn(error)
                    resolve([])
                    return false
                })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Why not return true?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

**The return type of `SQLStatementErrorCallback` is `boolean` (and not `void`) because it's used to indicate whether the error was handled or not.**

If the error is handled (ie `return true`), the whole transaction doesn't fail. If it's not handled (ie `return false`), then it does. **You should only `return true` if you've been able to suitably recover from the error.**

Remember that `executeSql` is only used within a transaction (which is created via `db.transaction` or `db.readTransaction`). A transaction accepts it's own success and error callbacks.

You can check the this in the source code by working backwards from this: https://github.com/nolanlawson/node-websql/blob/7b45bf108a9cffb1c7e16b9a7dfec47be8361850/lib/websql/WebSQLTransaction.js#L64-L68

```js
if (batchTask.sqlErrorCallback(self, res.error)) {
  // user didn't handle the error
  self._error = res.error;
  return onDone();
}
```